# Select all rows after a certain id from other table

Tags: sql, sqlite

For an assignment I have to do certain consults from a db.

[image: Here is what the database looks like.]

I need to find all the moves that the pokemon "bulbasaur" has and list their names, power, pp and accuracy.

I've tried this command and I get only one move out of 9 as a result:

```
SELECT name, power, pp, accuracy
FROM MOVES
WHERE id=(SELECT move_id FROM POKEMONS_MOVES WHERE pokemon_id=(SELECT id 
FROM POKEMONS WHERE name="bulbasaur"));

vine-whip|45|25|100
```

I am using sqlite3 btw. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is a CrossRef table in between, this can be easily achieved through Joins.

```html
SELECT 
    m.name, m.type_id, m.power, m.pp, m.accuracy
FROM 
    Moves m
INNER JOIN 
    Pokemons_Moves pm ON pm.move_id = m.id
INNER JOIN
    Pokemons p ON p.id = pm.pokemon_id
WHERE
    p.name = "bulbasaur"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using [scalar subqueries](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#subq):

> ```
> WHERE id=(SELECT ...)
> ```

This means that if the subquery returns more than one row, the database ignores all rows but the first. (Other databases will error out if that happens.)

To search through all IDs returned by the subquery, you have to use the [IN operator](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#in_op):

```
SELECT name, power, pp, accuracy
FROM Moves
WHERE id IN (SELECT move_id
             FROM Pokemons_Moves
             WHERE pokemon_id = (SELECT id
                                 FROM Pokemons
                                 WHERE name = 'bulbasaur'));
```

(The second subquery returns only one value.)

Comment: Thanks, that answered my question perfectly.